# Lifting a real quadratic twist of an Elliptic Curve to the modular curve

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms, moduli-spaces

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve of conductor $N\cdot p^2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, defined by the equation
$$y^2=x^3+p^2b\cdot x + p^3\cdot c$$
and parametrized by a map
$$X_{0}(N\cdot {p}^{2})\rightarrow E$$
and let $E_{\sqrt(p)}$ be the curve
$$y^2=x^3+b\cdot x+c$$
parametrized by a map
$$X_{0}(N)\rightarrow E_{\sqrt(p)}$$
(Here, $p$ is a prime greater than or equal to $5$, and we assume that $E_{\sqrt(p)}$ reduces well at $p$.)

Both become isomorphic over $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{p}]$.
Is there a lift of that isomorphism to a morphism:
$$X_{0}(N\cdot {p}^{2})\rightarrow X_{0}(N)$$
or
$$X_{0}(N)\rightarrow X_{0}(N\cdot {p}^{2})$$
and if so, can that morphism be described explicitly?

If it is not possible in general, can we classify the cases where such a lift exists?

(EDIT: If this question is stupid, feel free to tell me and to tell me why.)

Comment: Your second curve $E_{\sqrt{p}}$, am I right assuming it is the curve defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ obtained by twisting $E$ by $p$ ? If so the conductor of it is $p^2N$ in most cases, unless $p$ divided $N$ and you are lucky.

Comment: No. $E$ is the quadratic twist of $E_{\sqrt{p}}$ by $p$.

Comment: Well there's always a forgetful morphism $X_0(Np^2)\to X_0(N)$.